# Roach PHP http requests

Tags: php, laravel

I need to make GET request with using Roach PHP. It works if I'm using yield generator, but without I received just inside parameters of requests.
On example, I'm trying next:

```
$result = new Request(
        'GET',
        'https://stackoverflow.com/',
        [$this, 'testParse']
    );
```

and next:

```
$result = $this->request(
        'GET',
        'https://stackoverflow.com/',
        'testParse'
    );
```

or next:

```
$result = new GuzzleRequest('GET', 'https://stackoverflow.com/');
```

works only with yield:

```
yield $this->request(
            'GET',
            'https://stackoverflow.com/',
            'testParse'
        );
```

Is it possible to run it without yield?